# Understanding a q-sql query with a sublist

Tags: kdb

```
items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10
bolt  8     20
cam   0     15
cog   3     20

q)select {x}[prices] sublist' prices from tab
```

I am just getting into kdb q-sql and I saw some legacy code which is similar to the above. I was wondering if someone could explain the meaning behind this query. Especially the usage of the '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query here is applying `sublist` - which is a function that will return a sublist of `x` elements in `y`.

The `'` in this statement specifies that the function is applied to each element in the list.

I believe this can explained with a simple example.
If we take two lists:

```
x:1 2 3
y:(1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;10 11 12)
```

And I apply `sublist'` as follows:

```
q)x sublist' y
,1
5 6
10 11 12
```

The first element of x has been applied to the first level of y. And so on.

Comment: Thank u so much. Where did u find documentation for the ' ?

Comment: The documentation for [each-both `'`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both) is on the kx wiki. You can find the entry for `'` and other operators listed on the [reference card](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/card/#overloads).